# How to bind List nested in Class

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a problem with bindings. I need to bind List from this

```cs
public class DLHY_ADMIN_VIEW
    {
        public string VyslednaSuma { get; set; }
        public List<DLHY> Dlhy { get; set; }
    }
```

into this

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DLHY_}" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedItem="{Binding VybranyDLH}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" ColumnSpacing="0">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding VyslednaSuma}" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding KTO}" Margin="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding KOMU}" Margin="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding KOĽKO,StringFormat='{0:N}€'}" Margin="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding KEDY}" Margin="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Popis}" Margin="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

"DLHY" is

```cs
[DynamoDBTable("DLHY")]
    public class DLHY
    {
       [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string KTO { get; set; }
        public string KOMU { get; set; }
        public double KOĽKO { get; set; }
        public string KEDY { get; set; }
        public string Popis { get; set; }
    }
```

"DLHY_" is `public ObservableCollection<DLHY_ADMIN_VIEW> DLHY_ { get; set; }`.

How it should be done ? Is it possible to do it this way ? Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to display all of the elements of `Dlhy` from all the elements of `DLHY_`, then you will need to first flatten the data using LINQ.  Or you could try using Grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Comment: @Crudar,According to yourcode, if you just want to display DLHY element, you can just bind Dlhy to CollectionView, like this article:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-collectionview2/, but if you want to display grouped data, you can take a look the link that Jason provided.

Comment: What problem are you facing with your current implementation?